# Using shared_examples_for for mix a module into an rspec context

Tags: rspec, ruby-2.0

I included constants from modules in rspec using shared_examples_for

```
shared_examples_for 'Constants' do
  include AllTestData.UserConstants
end
# for example I have AllTestData.UserConstants::USER_NAME = 'John Dorian'

describe Users do
  include_context 'Constants'
  p USER_NAME   
end
```

When I used to ruby 1.9.2 it work. 
Now I use ruby 2.0.0. and now It is raise error -  NameError: uninitialized constant USER_NAME

Why now it fail and how I can fix it? Thanks

Comment: include by: AllTestData::UserConstants

Answer (score 3):

This has to do with how the rules of constant lookup changed. For some history see [Making Sense of Constant Lookup in Ruby by John Firebaugh](http://jfire.io/blog/2011/01/21/making-sense-of-constant-lookup-in-ruby/). You'll notice that in 1.8 when an instance of an object was `instance_eval`'d constant look up was performed lexically. This changed in 1.9. In fact, 1.9, had several iterations and `class_eval` constant look up was not consistent between versions.

It seems that in Ruby 2.0, the rules for constant look up went back to the 1.8 way. So now, `instance_exec` which RSpec leans heavily on, goes back to lexical constant rules and will not search up the hierarchy.

You can see this in action:

```
class Foo
  X = "Does it work?"
end

f = Foo.new
f.instance_exec do
  p X
end
```

In Ruby 1.9.2, this outputs: `"Does it work?"

In Ruby 2.0.0, this outputs: `NameError: uninitialized constant X`

You could probably work around this with by delegating to the class with `self.class::CONSTANT`:

```
module Bar
  B = "A bit wonky"
end

example_group = Class.new do
  include Bar
end

example = example_group.new

example.instance_exec do
  p self.class::B
end
# => "A bit wonky"
```